# Check if context is being viewed or in focus

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have an Alert Dialog that I am displaying whenever there is a response from the server or an API. It looks like so:

```
public void showDeveloperDialog(Context context, String responseMessage) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Response");
    alertDialog.setMessage(responseMessage);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

If the dialog gets called from example Activity A and there is a delay with the response prompting the user goes to another activity (Activity B), the app crashes since the context that called it is not in view.

How can I check to ensure that the dialog only gets shown if the initial context is in view?

Comment: Logcat please share

Comment: Either you need to destroy the alertDialog instance when activity is being killed or you need to change your logic of showing the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast the context to an Activity to check if the Activity is finished or not, and only display if its not finished using [isFinishing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) method

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    if (!activity.isFinishing()) {
        // You can now display the dialog
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```